# How to use Protocols and Delegates with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a **Welcome** controller as the base. It presents **Login** or **Signup** controller modally based on the button the user clicks. Now once user presses login in **Login** controller, I dismiss the **Login** Controller and notify **Welcome** controller that user pressed login. I do this using delegates and protocols.

***Problem***: Now the issue is that my **Signup** controller does not have the sign up button. It instead directs the user to a **SecondSignup** controller and that directs to a **ThirdSignup** controller - all part of a **UINavigationController**. How can the sign up button in this **ThirdSignup** controller notify the **Welcome** controller that user has pressed signup? To avoid confusion, I have specified the hierarchy below

This is the Hierarchy

- Welcome -> Login
- Welcome -> SignUp -> SecondSignUp -> ThirdSignUp

```
protocol SignupDelegate{
      func signupButtonPressed()
}
```

In ThirdSignUp

```
class ThirdSignupController {
      var delegate: SignupDelegate!

      @objc func handleSignup{
         delegate.signupButtonPressed()
         self.dismiss()
      }
}
```

In Welcome Controller

```
class WelcomeController: SignupDelegate {

      @objc func handleSignupButtonPressed(){
         let signupController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SignupController())
         self.present(signupController, animated: true)
         // ****
         // **** Where do I set the delegate? I am not referencing ThirdSignupController()****
         // ****
      }

      func signupButtonPressed(){
         print("User has pressed sign up button in ThirdSignupController")
      }      
}
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution would simply be to carry on the delegate through all view controllers until the third one.
So define a `delegate` property in every view controller (`SignUp`, `SecondSignUp` and `ThirdSignUp`), and when presenting the first sign up controller, assign the delegate as the `Welcome` view controller. e.g.

```
// WelcomeController.swift
let signupController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SignupController())
signUpController.delegate = self
```

And now for both `SecondSignUp` and `ThirdSignUp` pass on the delegate before presenting them like so:

```
nextViewController.delegate = self.delegate
```

And by the end of this you should have your `ThirdSignUp` view controller have the delegate set as the `Welcome` view controller.

On a side note, it's best to use delegates as `weak` references to avoid retain cycles and memory leaks, especially when using the same reference through multiple controllers, so define your delegate properties like so:

`weak var delegate: SignUpDelegate`

To allow that, define your protocol as:

`protocol SignUpDelegate: AnyObject { ... }`

Comment: Great solution however before I mark your answer as right, for simplicity purpose, I posted only three sign up process pages. In my app however, there are various conditions. For ex: I verify one of the user's textfield input and depending on that input, different controllers are presented. Do you think delegates and protocols is an elegant solution here? Or should I go for notifications and observers?

Comment: Notifications and observers are never elegant solutions as they are indirect and thus hard to track, and generally are bad practice to use. You should really use notifications if there is no other choice. Another simple solution though, is closures, which you can say are essentially another form of delegate and you can actually use it along with the delegates. Look it up for more information. Good luck ;)